# How can I know whether `eval` execution finished if there are mutiple promises inside it

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using `eval` to execute a string as javascript code in a nodejs application. The problem is I don't know whether the `eval` execution is finished or not if the string includes multiple promises.

```
const userFind = 'function usersFind(db, userAge, userNameLast) {\
  const useDb = db.db("test");\
  const query = {\
    "user.age": { $gt: userAge },\
    "user.name.last": userNameLast\
  };\
  const returnData = new Promise(resolve => {\
    const arrayData = useDb.collection("users").find(query).limit(1).toArray();\
    resolve(arrayData);\
  });\
  return returnData;\
}\
let results = usersFind(db, 5, "Lee", 1);\
results.then(r => {\
  r.forEach(doc => {\
    console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));\
  });\
});\
results = usersFind(db, 5, "Lee", 1);\
results.then(r => {\
  r.forEach(doc => {\
    console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));\
  });\
});\
';
```

the above script defines a string includes two promises. If I run the code as below:

`eval(userFind)`

The eval function returns without waiting for the promises.
How can I know when the two promises have been finished or not?

Comment: Question is why use code as string and then use `eval` to process it?

Comment: first solution: dont use eval?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chain `.then()` to `eval()` call. You can alternatively use `Function` constructor

```js
let fn = `() => 
           new Promise(resolve => 
             setTimeout(resolve, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1200), "resolved"))`;
           
let promiseString = new Function(`return ${fn}`)();

promiseString()
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: I think it only works if my last statement inside the `eval` is promise, right?

Comment: Which specific code are you referencing? Note, no value is returned from function passed to `.then()` at `usersFind()` calls

Comment: Do you mean I need to add `return results` at the end of my code?

Comment: There is no function to return from. at the close of the string. What is expected result?

Comment: I am confused about your example.  Do you mean I need to copy all your code inside a string and run it in `eval`?

Comment: @ZhaoYi No. You can alternatively use `new Function()` instead of `eval()`. Though using `eval()` should return same result. `const userFind = \`function usersFind(a, b) {
  const query = {
    "user.age": a,
    "user.name.last": b
  };
  const returnData = new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(query);
  });
  return returnData;
}\`; results = new Function(\`return ${userFind}\`)()(1, 2);results.then(data => console.log(data));`

Comment: ok, the problem for me is that all I have is a string. So I need to run the string as javascript code. Can I avoid using `eval` in this case?

Comment: Yes, you can use `new Function()`, see code at Answer and previous comment. `var template = 123; console.log(\`${template}\`)` is use of a template literal.

Comment: ok, I see. So the string passed in `new Function()` has to return a promise right?

Comment: @ZhaoYi Yes. You can the chain `.then()` to the function call to await `Promise` resolution or rejection.